# how to get facebook user avatar in android

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api, android-imageview

I'm using facebook sdk. I want get current logged user avatar. 
My code:

```
img_url = new URL("https:/graph.facebook.com/" + user.getId() + "/picture?type=large");
                            InputStream is = img_url.openConnection().getInputStream();
                            Bitmap avatar;
                            avatar = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(is);
```

following exception found:

```
java.net.UnknownHostException: https:/graph.facebook.com/100001119045663/picture?type=large
```

How to solve this exception?